# How can I check how many edits suggested by me are currently pending review?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I am doing a lot of edits, but I don't have permission to edit posts, so my edits have to be reviewed. I want to know how many my post are currently waiting for review. How can I check how many edits have been suggested by me and are currently pending review? Is there any way to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your profile.  On the list of tabs, go to **activity** and then **suggestions**.  It'll show the total number of suggestions (reviewed and pending), the list of them, and will allow you to see who has approved/rejected each review.

Comment: I want to see count - not a list

Comment: @Ty221: I don't think there's a way to do that.  The count only shows *total* suggestions.  Are you just suggesting a way to show a count of pending reviews?  Your question wording didn't imply a feature request.

Comment: Are you really making so many suggestions that you can't count the open ones is a few seconds? Stuff doesn't tend to sit in that queue for all that long.