# See the count of suggested edits currently pending review

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Yesterday I asked followed question - [How can I check how many edits suggested by me are currently pending review?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199669/how-can-i-check-how-many-edits-suggested-by-me-are-currently-pending-review) - and I received an answer that it is impossible to see how many of my suggested edits are currently pending review. I am requesting to add a field in user profile how many his suggested edits are currently pending review. Why ? To see how many reputation can you earn and simply for curiosity :) I will be not hard to implement, but fine for SE's users. I am doing a lot of suggestions and I wanna know how many of it has been currently approved/rejected and how many are currently for review waiting.

Comment: You can see all suggested edits you made [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1952862/ty221?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) so it's only a matter of adding another details in the existing view. Good idea, will make a mockup shortly.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yeah, I know that I can see the list, but I wanna see count :) I hope that staff will implement that shortly

Comment: I prefer to see suggested edit status rather then just plain counter, anyway feature requests can wait for long years so don't build your hopes up too high.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes, I know - e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190130/allow-post-banned-users-to-edit-their-removed-answers-questions that is waiting fast 3 months...

Comment: Don't accept my answer just yet, it's just a suggestion - let the team actually implement it first. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Unaccepted :)

Comment: Never too late, I guess? :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard better late than never ;)

Answer (score 13):

Good idea, but I prefer to see the actual status of the suggested edit i.e. approved/rejected/pending:

> [image]

(mockup only, all the above were actually approved)

#### Related:

- [Improving how suggested edits are displayed in your activity history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122581/improving-how-suggested-edits-are-displayed-in-your-activity-history)
- [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor)

Answer (score 1):

I like this idea.

It could work in a similar way to helpful flags page where you can see all your flags with their status. For rejected edits, it will be important for the users to see why they were rejected.